# Database Link in DB2

Tags: db2, dblink

How to interconnect two different DB2 database hosted on two different IPs?
I mean I want to know is there anything in DB2 which is equivalent to Oracle's DBLink?
I am sitting on a DB2 Test environment and want to copy few rows for testing from production DB2 environment. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is something like that in DB2, called "three part names". I wrote a [small overview article](http://blog.4loeser.net/2013/09/oracle-dblink-and-db2-three-part-names.html) for my blog that has an example and all the interesting links to documentation.

The steps involve creating a DRDA wrapper (DRDA is the communication protocol for DB2), then providing the connection details on how to connect to the remote database server. After that you can query the remote tables without any additional setup and address them by server/schema/table - hence the "three part name". Note that you might need to use `CATALOG TCPIP NODE` first to make a remote server known by its IP address. Something like `catalog tcpip node yourserver remote 192.0.32.67 server db2inst1`

Comment: when I have executed the command "create wrapper drda" I got the message => DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0601N  The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing
name "DRDA" of type "WRAPPER".  SQLSTATE=42710

Comment: Also for the next statement in your blog there is no IP address or host name given for the remote database. "db2 => create server myserver type db2/cs version 10.5 wrapper drda authorization hloeser password "secrets4you" options (dbname 'DBTWO')". So question is how the system will know where is the remote database.

Comment: What version and edition of DB2 are you using? The statements in my blog are examples that you need to adapt to your IP addresses and server/database names. Did you look at CREATE SERVER and its options? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002170.html

Comment: The error you saw when trying to create the wrapper indicates that it was already created ("identical to the existing...").

Comment: I am actually using IBM BigInsights version 3.x where there is a DB2 database under the hood

Comment: Could you please give me a one liner example of create server statement which should contain IP Address or host name

Comment: Then it is a different story because the federation feature is the core of BigInsights BigSQL. There is separate documentation on what is officially available. The missing piece is the CATALOG TCPIP NODE command which I added to the answer

Comment: the version I found is DB2 v10.6.0.2, in local and remote bothside

Comment: When I am executing the below in local db : `db2 "create server myserver type db2/cs version 10.6.0.2 wrapper drda authorization user@xx.xx.xx.xx password "mypas" options (dbname 'mydb')` -- I am getting error like `DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token ".xx.xx.xx" was found following "on
user@xx".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87634/discussion-between-henrik-loeser-and-koushik-chandra).